# How to retrieve rows that has all features using Propel?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, propel

I am working on project which is in symfony 1.0

I have problem in creating propel query.

I have two table

1. car

   ```
   id     name
   1       a
   2       b
   3       c
   ```
2. feature

   ```
   id    car_id    feature
   1      2         f1
   2      2         f2
   3      2         f3
   4      1         f1
   5      3         f3
   6      3         f2
   7      3         f4
   ```

Here is a [SQLFiddle with table and value](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a4f60).

I have feature `array(f1,f2,f3)`. Now I want only cars which has all three features i.e which is "b" in our case.

I have tried but not gives satisfied result

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->clearSelectColumn();
$c->addSelectColumn(CarPeer::NAME);
$c->addSelectColumn(FeaturePeer::CAR_ID);
$c->addJoin(CarPeer::ID,FeaturePeer::CAR_ID,Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
$c->add(FeaturePeer::FEATURE,array(f1,f2,f3),Criteria::IN);
$c->addGroupBy(CarPeer::ID);
$resultset = CarPeer::doSelectRs($c);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the SQl you want (seems to work in my [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a4f60/13/0) anyway):

```
SELECT car_id FROM
  (SELECT COUNT(car_id) AS feature_count, car_id FROM feature
    WHERE feature IN ('f1', 'f2', 'f3') GROUP BY car_id
  ) car_features
WHERE car_features.feature_count=3
```

Now to get that in Propel you need to do something like:

```
$features = array("f1", "f2", "f3");
$featureCount = FeatureQuery::create()
  ->withColumn("COUNT(car_id)", "feature_count")
  ->add(FeaturePeer::FEATURE, $features, Criteria::IN)
  ->addGroupBy(CarPeer::ID);
$cars = CarQuery::create()
  ->addSelectQuery($featureCount, "car_features")
  ->where("car_features.feature_count = ?", sizeof($features))
  ->find();
```